# count the occurrence of successive character from a String of single word in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string

```
 String alpha="AAAABBCCCDAA";
```

I need to do some processing in this string and count each character and should produce result like

```
 4A2B3C1D2A
```

My code is working fine but counts A as a whole does not count the last A individually

```
    String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String alpha = "AAAABBCCCDAA";

    for (char a : text.toCharArray()) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (char b : alpha.toCharArray()) {
            if (a == b)
                counter++;
        }

        if (counter != 0) {

            System.out.print(counter);
            System.out.print(a);
        }
```

And the result is : 6A2B3C1D

What kind of logic and ideas should I put in the code?

Comment: if a !=b, stop looping?

Comment: You should take a different approach, loop over your `alpha` and then do a simple 3 step algorithm: 1.) Take the current character. 2.) Continue looping until you encounter a different character. Take note of the number of occurences. 3.) Add counter + character to your output. Rinse and repeat until you are at the end of your `alpha`

Answer (score 0):

You need not use the nested loop for this simplistic requirement, 
Since you have to just find the successive characters you can achieve this in **O(n) time complexity**.

```
  public static void printOccurrences( String str )
  {
    int len = str.length();
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    char contChar = arr[0];
    int count = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
    {
      if( contChar == arr[i] )
      {
        count++;

        // this below condition helps you to add that last A missed frequency
        if( i + 1 >= arr.length )
        { // Since after this iteration loop will not enter the else block
          sb.append( count ).append( contChar );
        }
      }
      else
      {
        sb.append( count ).append( contChar );
        contChar = arr[i];
        count = 0;
        i--;
      }
    }
    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
  }

   printOccurrences("AAAABBCCCDAA"); // Input
```

and your Output is **4A2B3C1D2A**

Complete program : https://ideone.com/eh5eQy